# PyASN1 der decoding equivalent in Objective C/Swift

Tags: python, objective-c, swift

I am currently making a GUI-based OS X application based on a certain python program. I have translated nearly all of the python into Swift (and going from a basically untyped language to the type Gestapo was seriously not fun...), but I'm stuck on one part. At one point, the python code decodes der encoded data and I have no clue how to do an equivalent transformation in Swift (or Obj-C).

The python code:

```
from pyasn1.codec.der.decoder import decode as der_decode

...

data = der_decode(derdata)[0]
```

Can someone point me in the direction of what that should look like in Swift ( / Obj-C)?

Comment: If that is a library you can put the h-file in the bridging header.

Comment: If what is a library? As far as I'm aware, python doesn't mix with Swift very well